# R Duplicate Specific Rows In A Data Frame

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, row

I have a decent-size data frame of tasks done by different people (and some other information about the task in other columns).

If I get a frequency count of who has done how many tasks I get something like this made-up example data:

```
Name       Count
John       27
Jack       14
Jill       31
John,Jack  7
Jack and Jill  11
John/Jill  3
Jack+John,Jill 1
```

My goal is to duplicate jobs done by multiple people. If I run a frequency count I want something like this:

```
Name    Count
John    35    
Jack    33
Jill    46
```

I need to duplicate any rows of the data frame where multiple people worked on a job so that the same job is listed as being done solely by each person that worked on it.

I have a list of all the names, but not the various connectors put between them (I've got Jack+Jill,Jack/Jill, Jack and Jill, and other connections between names).

I'm fairly new to R, and I wrote this as:

```
unlisted = unlist(data$"Name")
temp1 = data[grepl(employeenames[1], unlisted, fixed = TRUE), ]
temp1[, "Name"] = employeenames[1]
for(i in 2:length(employeenames)){
  temp2 = data[grepl(employeenames[i], unlisted, fixed = TRUE), ]
  temp2[ ,"Name"] = employeenames[i]
  temp1 = rbind(temp1, temp2)
}
data = temp1
```

This works, as far as I've seen, but I've repeatedly been told (or rather, read stackoverflow answers where people have been told) that `rbind` and `for` loops do not mix. It seems like too many lines for what should be a simple operation.

**Question**

What is a faster or more "correct" way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a tidyverse version:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data_frame(Name = c("John", "Jack", "Jill", "John,Jack", "Jack and Jill", "John/Jill", "Jack+John,Jill"), 
                 Count = c(27L, 14L, 31L, 7L, 11L, 3L, 1L))

df %>% 
    separate_rows(Name, sep = '[,/+]| and ') %>% 
    group_by(Name) %>% 
    summarise(Count = sum(Count))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   Name  Count
#>   <chr> <int>
#> 1 Jack     33
#> 2 Jill     46
#> 3 John     38
```